# NSIS, run one action as administator

Tags: uac, nsis

I have an installation that require only user privilegies, but this installation should remove previous files or call uninstaller if it exists

Is there way in NSIS to run one action(DeleteFile, RunExe) as administrator?

Comment: If installing only requires user privilegies, how can uninstall require admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elevation is per process and you cannot go back down once you have elevated.

You should create a little helper nsis app that performs your required actions (RequestExecutionLevel admin alone is not enough, you also need to use [UserInfo::GetAccountType](http://pastebin.com/EvMkyLLt#NSIS%3aRequireAdmin)) Use [ShellExecute](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellExecWait) with the runas verb to start a elevated process.